# Google Maps Geocoding not working on TSO Host webhosting

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following code to convert an address to longitude and latitude.  The code is taken from http://www.phpmoot.com/php-get-latitudelongitude-from-an-address-with-google-map/

```
$address = '201 S. Division St., Ann Arbor, MI 48104'; // Google HQ
$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);

$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

echo $address.'<br>Lat: '.$lat.'<br>Long: '.$long;
```

This works fine on my previous hosting, but when I moved the site to TSO host, it no longer works.  What reasons might there be for this?

I've tried using a browser api key in the url and a server api key and that doesn't work either.  like this

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&key=****API_KEY_GOES_HERE****&sensor=false
```

Any help welcome.  TSO Host support can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Can you check the console logs for Javascript errors on googleapis and if you see anything post here?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Is this shared hosting where the previous host wasn't?

Comment: Both are shared hosting

Comment: Can you post the page address if it is public?

Comment: I can't because I'm using it in the backend of Wordpress.  When I save a post I'm grabbing an address from a field and updating 2 other fields with the longitude/latitude.

Comment: I can not really check something on backend but If you can implement this code in your page we can have a better Idea on what is going wrong.
Code is too long for a comment.

Partially this part:
  var center;
        var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': $AdressYouGotFromThePost}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   var mycenter = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());//
   var mapProp = {
    center:mycenter,
    zoom:11
   };

Comment: I've create a page here http://thenewschoolart.org/tester.php.  It has the code from the example site I gave above

Comment: To use it on page you need to add this too into page :

<script async="" defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURACCESSKEYHERE&amp;callback=initialize&amp;libraries=places">
 </script>

Comment: The hosts are saying that the code works when they test it on their cpanel hosting but not on their cloud hosting.  they are still looking into it.  I suspect it is out of my control.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89830/discussion-between-luke-seall-and-cntkctn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the php method to convert the address to longitude and latitude like this example http://www.phpmoot.com/php-get-latitudelongitude-from-an-address-with-google-map/

was causing the api limits to be reached on the TSO host shared cloud server.  Using an API key didn't seem to make any difference.  The solution was to not use the php method and instead use the Javascript method as per Googles example here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure it is server related I would recommend you to try using the JS in page. Please try to implement below code with changing your div ID and KEY. Also pass the address variable you have to related place.

```
   <script>
     function initialize() {
        var center;
        var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': $AdressYouGotFromThePost}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var mycenter = new  google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());//
            var mapProp = {
            center:mycenter,
            zoom:11
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("YOURDIVID"),mapProp);
        var request = {
                location: mycenter,
                radius: '20000',
                types: ['bar,night_club,cafe,museum,movie_theater,zoo,aquapark']
            };
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);            
    }
    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
                createPhotoMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function createPhotoMarker(place) {
      var photos = place.photos;
      if (!photos) {
        return;
      }

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        title: place.name
        //icon: photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 55, 'maxHeight': 55})
      });
      //console.log(photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 105, 'maxHeight': 105}));

      var contenthtml = "<p>"+place.name+"</p><img src="+photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 105, 'maxHeight': 105})+" width='105px'/>";
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content:contenthtml
          });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
          map.setZoom(17);
          map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
          });

        }
    });
 }

 </script>

     <script async="" defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURACCESSKEYHERE&amp;callback=initialize&amp;libraries=places">
```

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but that code just gives me a white screen.  What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: I am checking the same page you sent before and I dont see the script I posted and the div that you need to create.

Comment: It supposed to look something like this map.

http://askwheretogo.com/question/where-to-go-in-barcelona/

Comment: Thanks for your help CntkCtn.  According to TSO Host, it is because it is a shared cloud server and it is reaching the API request limit.  They said I need to use an api key.  I've tried it with browser key and server key and it doesn't make a difference.  Is there something else I need?

Comment: I believe you need to use JS instead of PHP and you need the API key for that. And you can get it from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key